# Gram-Schmidt with curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

Can we use Gram-Schmidt to estimate principal directions of curvature at a point p on a manifold?

Suppose for any $tV \in T_pM$, we use the exponential map exp(V_t) to get a curve $\gamma: \Re \to M$, where \gamma(0) = p. We then calculate the curvature of this curve at p, and pick a direction $V$ that maximizes the curvature. We can use Gram-Schmidt to pick orthogonal directions based on the curvature. Does this **very special** (normal) coordinate system based on curvature have a name?

Comment: The curvature of the curve is *not* the same thing as the normal curvature of the surface in that direction. Only if you take a *plane* section of the surface will you get agreement of the curvatures (up to sign). See Meusnier's formula on p. 51 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). The same formula holds for hypersurfaces in $\Bbb R^n$ with $n>3$.

Comment: Why is the surface special here? (I know about the sectional curvature) The procedure that I'm proposing above seems like a natural way to define a coordinate system. Is there anything missing or wrong there?

Comment: Did you try to understand my comment? To talk about principal curvatures you need to have a hypersurface, and principal curvatures are an *extrinsic* notion, whereas sectional curvatures are *intrinsic*. And, as I said, you can have wildly different curvatures at a point for curves on the manifold with the same tangent direction.

Comment: yes I did misunderstand: about your last statement "uniqueness of the curvature with the same choice of tangent direction":  You can express this procedure also in terms of exponential maps. I can pick a $V \in T_pM$ map it to the manifold and find the curvature of the resulting curve. Wouldn't this uniquely identify the curvature for a V?

Comment: Well, yes, if you know you have geodesics, that's quite different. That's not so easy to do in practice, though. If you have the exponential map, you already have Gauss normal coordinates, so there's no need for any further coordinate systems. By the way, it's not always possible to integrate from tangent directions and get a coordinate system. You need the Lie brackets of the vector fields to vanish.

Comment: Suppose I can do this (e.g. the manifold is embedded in R^D). My understanding is that you get a "normal" coordinate for any choice of orthonormal coordinates in the tangent space. This particular coordinate with maximizing curvature directions is very special. Does it have a name?